# split dhcp subnet in two parts

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I am trying to split isc dhcp subnet, so that in one part(0..128) I have only reserved IPs, and in the other part(128..255) - dynamic range. I tried this configuration(bellow), but I always get a dynamic range from part 2.. even I am booting "node-1", which should get static IP by its MAC.

```
subnet 1.2.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.128 {
 next-server 1.2.3.199;
 filename "pxelinux.0";
 option routers 1.2.3.1;
 option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
 option domain-name "host.edu";
 option domain-name-servers 1.2.8.;
 option broadcast-address 1.2.3.255;

 default-lease-time -1;
 max-lease-time -1;

 host node-1 {
     hardware ethernet 00:00:00:01:01:5d;
     fixed-address 1.2.3.12;
     option host-name "node-1";
 }
}


subnet 1.2.3.128 netmask 255.255.255.128 {
 range dynamic-bootp 1.2.3.130 1.2.3.190;
  next-server 1.2.3.199;
 filename "pxelinux.0";
 option routers 1.2.3.1;
 option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
 option domain-name "host.edu";
 option domain-name-servers 1.2.8.23;
 option broadcast-address 1.2.3.255;

 default-lease-time -1;
 max-lease-time -1;
}
```

SoIt it possible to do my task? I need to separate the network, because of a management software behind dhcp.. otherwise I would not do this.

Answer (score 3):

Your configuration should look more like this:

```
subnet 1.2.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 1.2.3.128 1.2.3.254

 next-server 1.2.3.199;
 filename "pxelinux.0";
 option routers 1.2.3.1;
 option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
 option domain-name "host.edu";
 option domain-name-servers 1.2.8.;
 option broadcast-address 1.2.3.255;

 default-lease-time -1;
 max-lease-time -1;

 host node-1 {
     hardware ethernet 00:00:00:01:01:5d;
     fixed-address 1.2.3.12;
     option host-name "node-1";
 }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to avoid.. I know, that this works for sure.. but I need to split it in tow parts.. its not because of configuration, but of the management software (foreman smart proxy)